# How to utilize curl request in JMeter?

Tags: curl, httprequest, jmeter

I have a curl request and I want to utilize it in JMeter:

```
curl  -i -X POST -u 'anarinsky@aaa.com:a1234' -d "email=anarinsky@aaa.com" 
-k http://anarinsky.aaa.com/rest/secure/requestOrderMultipleAttr/skuOrderList/AAA_Prod_Go_d2/quantityAdult/1/quantityChild/1/email/anarinsky@aaa.com
```

What is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To simulate this curl call with JMeter you'll need:

[HTTP Request Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) configured as follows:

- **Server Name or IP:** anarinsky.aaa.com
- **Protocol:** http
- **Method:** POST
- **Path:** /rest/secure/requestOrderMultipleAttr/skuOrderList/AAA_Prod_Go_d2/quantityAdult/1/quantityChild/1/email/anarinsky@aaa.com
- **Parameters:** **Name:** email **Value:** anarinsky@aaa.com

[HTTP Authorization Manager](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-http-basic-authentication-jmeter) as a child of HTTP Request (if you want to use username/password only for this HTTP Request) or at the same level if you intend to use it for all requests in scope.

- **Username:** anarinsky@aaa.com
- **Password:** a1234

Comment: How can I see the results.  I tried to add "Save Responses to a file" element - did not see the results.  Also, if I have more questions would it be possible to contact you?

Comment: View Results Tree Listener can be used to display comprehensive information on request/response details including response body. http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree